# How to remove key from my input upon input reset?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a search form with multiple inputs.

The form has a reset button to start a new search. Currently I have it working so that the value gets cleared from the state. The problem is that the key value is not being removed and so the input is being included in the new search with just an empty key. This is causing the search to include empty keys as part of the query string.

For example. This is a query string with the added empty key:

`http://api/ixmasterdocument?filter=IDXT002|&filter=IDXT001|1111`

As you can see the `filter=IDXT002|` is empty and being included in query string with the correct key value pair `filter=IDXT001|1111`

Here is my reset method that clears the key value from state.

```
clear = () => {
  let emptyValues = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.formValues))
  Object.keys(emptyValues).forEach(key => emptyValues[key] = "")
  this.setState({
    formValues: emptyValues,
    contracts:[],
  }) 
}
```

Here is my inputchange method..

```
 handleInputChange = (e) => {
      console.log("==handleInputChange==")
      let newValues = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.formValues))
      newValues[e.target.name] = e.target.value
      this.setState({
        formValues: newValues
      })
      console.log("newFormValues is: " + JSON.stringify(newValues))
    }
```

Here is the submit method..

```
 handleFormSubmit = event => {  
    event.preventDefault();
    const formData = this.state.formValues
    let query = '';
    let keys = Object.keys(formData);
    keys.forEach(k => { 
      if (query !== "")
      query += `&`;
      query += `filter=`
      query += `${k}|${formData[k]}`

     })
     return this.loadContracts(query);
    };
```

Here is the input component with reset button..

```
<form className="form-inline col-md-12" onReset={this.props.handleFormReset}>

   {this.props.labels.map(label => (
     <div className="card border-0 mx-auto" style={styles} key={label.Id}>
          <ul className="list-inline ">
             <span>
               <li>
                 <Labels  htmlFor={label.DisplayName} >{label.DisplayName}:</Labels>
               </li>
               <li >
                 <div>
                  <Input  
                   key={label.Id}
                   onChange={this.props.handleInputChange}
                   value={this.props.formValues[label.DataField] ||""}
                   type="search"
                   maxLength="999"
                   style={{height:34}}
                   name={label.DataField ||""}

                   className={"form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2"} 
                   id={label.DataField}
                 />
                 State: {this.props.formValues[label.DataField]}

                 </div>

               </li> 
             </span>
         </ul>
     </div>
   ))}

  <div className=" col-sm-12">

  <Button
        style={{ float: "left", marginBottom: 10 }} 
        className="btn btn-success"
        type="submit"
        onClick={this.props.handleFormSubmit}
      >
        Search
      </Button>

      <Help />

      <Button
        style={{ float: "left", marginBottom: 10 }} 
        className="btn btn-secondary"
        // type="reset"
        onClick={this.props.clear}
      >
        Reset
      </Button>
  </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: you want to remove all the keys and values or with some condition? also can you show the `handleFormSubmit` method?

Comment: Just the keys and values that have been used in the previous search. And just to reset them so they may or may not be used in the new search

Comment: @MayankShukla added the handleFormSubmit method

Comment: i think, you should put the check in handleSubmit and skip all the key value where `value=''`, like this: `if(formData[k]) { if (query !== "") /*.....rest code*/}`, reset part seems ok, you are setting the `emptyValues[key] = ""` to clear the value.

Comment: @MayankShukla like this? `keys.forEach(k => { 
      if(formData[k])
      if (query !== "")
      query += `&`;`

Comment: yes but use `{}` with `if(formData[k])` and put everything in block.

Comment: ok this does the trick. The empty inputs are excluded from the query string. From the console I can see that the key is still in the state but is just being ignored. Could you make your comment an answer? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since You want to ignore/skip the key-value pairs in api call where `value=''`, so put the check in `handleSubmit` function and include only non-empty values.

Like this:

```
handleFormSubmit = event => {  
  event.preventDefault();
  const formData = this.state.formValues
  let query = '';
  let keys = Object.keys(formData);

  keys.forEach(k => {
    // here
    if(formData[k]) {
      if (query !== "")
        query += `&`;
      query += `filter=`
      query += `${k}|${formData[k]}`
    }
  })

  return this.loadContracts(query);
};
```

Or another possible way can be, setting `formValues` as `{}` in `clear` method. You are only clearing values not keys from that object, if you reset the variable then only new key-value will be available.

Like this:

```
clear = () => {
  this.setState({
    formValues: {},
    contracts:[],
  }) 
}
```

Comment: check the another possible way, that should also work.

Comment: That works for clearing the value as well. I still  need to include your if statement though to prevent it from being included in the query string